# How to pass implicitely Flash when dealing with multiple implict values in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I am currently struggling to find a way to implement alerts in a reusable and clean fashion. I am not sure if Play's flashing is only intended for redirects, but [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/oGh3gTmzrLA) indicates that there's a workaround for flashing with instances of class `Result`.

The workaround suggests to use an `implicit` parameter for the view, for example:

```
@(clientForm: Form[models.Client])(implicit flash: Flash)
```

And then simply do something like this:

```
val flash = play.api.mvc.Flash(Map("error" -> "Please select another id for this client"))
Ok(views.html.clients.new_client(boundForm)(flash))
```

The problem is that I do have multiple implicit parameters in my view, i.d.:

```
(implicit request: RequestHeader, messages: Messages, flash: Flash)
```

So the compiler complains with:

> Unspecified value parameters: flash: Flash, messages: Messages

How can I solve this?

Making `flash` implicit, as suggested in the (deleted) answer, didn't solve the problem. I still get this compile error:

> ambiguous implicit values:  both method request2flash in trait
>   Controller of type (implicit request:
>   play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)play.api.mvc.Flash  and value flash of type
>   play.api.mvc.Flash  match expected type play.api.mvc.Flash

Comment: You don't need to pass the flash implicit parameter since there is an implicit conversion happening from request to flash via request2flash method as shown in the new error.

Comment: For messages error, try `import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Samar, but when making `flash` implicit and not passing it to the view, I still get this compile error. I don't think that it has something to do with `Messages`, since everything worked before introducing `Flash`. Do you have any other suggestions how alerts can be implemented in a reusable way?

Comment: dont make flash implicit. the implicit is automatically passed in. I mean remove this line `implicit val flash = play.api.mvc.Flash(Map("error" -> "Please select another id for this client"))`

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying, but then how do I get the flash object into the view?

Comment: pls check the answer. your request parameter is turned into a Flash type because of the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the flash implicit parameter since there is an implicit conversion happening from request to flash via request2flash method as shown in the error.

Also, because you are getting an implicit flash already via request you don't need this line: `val flash = play.api.mvc.Flash(Map("error" -> "Please select another id for this client"))`

You can just use the `request` parameter as a Flash one because of the implicit conversion.

To fix the error for missing implicit messages: `import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I had it like this before already, but what I am trying to achieve is to use `flashing` with `Ok`, for example: `Ok(views.html.myPage(params)).flashing("success" -> "Yippie! Everything worked.")`. I don't get a compile error but the flash message simply won't be rendered.

Comment: In your views template you can use the flash object like this: @flash.get("success").getOrElse("Welcome!")

Comment: But then I get: `Cannot resolve symbol flash`. Also, Play gives me this warning: `[warn] play - You are using status code '200' with flashing, which should only be used with a redirect status!`.

Comment: It's working for me. Can you show your view template?